# Selecting several rows from a column

Tags: mysql

Below is the order table

```
order_table     
product_id  amount  price
1           2       4
1           5       4
2           2       4
2           3       4
3           4       4
4           3       4
4           2       4
4           2       4
5           4       4
5           1       4
6           1       4
6           1       4
```

And below is my values table

```
value_table 
product_id  value
1           a
1           b
1           c
2           a
2           b
2           c
3           a
3           d
3           c
4           a
4           d
4           c
5           a
5           b
5           c
6           a
6           d
6           c
```

What I want to achieve is the table below.

```
product_id  amount*price as total values
3           12                    a,c and not equal to b
4           28                    a,c and not equal to b
6           8                     a,c and not equal to b
```

I do understand that once you group the product_id then it will only show you a value ='a' or 'c'. and that's fine what I am looking for is the products that contain both a,c but  don't want a product_id that has a value equal to = b
So to summarize only 3,4,6 should appear grouped so that I don't sum up duplicates of the same order.

Comment: product_id 3 must have a total of 16, right?

Comment: yeah sorry, i created a fake table so I didn't give away my database away. haha but yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id,SUM(amount*price) as Totalprice
FROM order_table
WHERE product_id NOT IN
      (SELECT product_id
       FROM value_table
       WHERE value='b')
GROUP BY product_id
```

**Explanation:**

The inner query selects a list of product_ids which have b as value. So inner query will have a result of (1,2,5).

The outer query calculates the sum of prices of product_ids which are not present in that list. i.e., Not in the list of (1,2,5)

**Result:**

```
PRODUCT_ID  TOTAL
3           16
4           28
6           8
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9502e/3).

Comment: That will work with that set of data, but in a massive database in which has more values that I wish to care for...it will not work. What i am looking for is something that will filter 'a' and 'c', after I want it to exclude any b's as well from the a and c table.. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @PedroBernardo: You mean you have more value to be excluded like 'b','e','f'...?